# How to open second drawer in REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, react-native-drawer

I must do 2 drawer at both sides and a bottom tab navigator. I tried to do it with react-navigation but I couldnt because openDrawer code just opens one of them so I stuck please help me. How can I give drawers ID, key or another method.

React Native

```
<Button onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer}>
<Button/>  //left drawer opens 
<Button onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer}>
<Button/>
```

I tried your code but I got TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating 'this.props.navigation.dispatch')

```
<Button title='open the drawer' onPress={this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer('drawerOpenLeft'))}></Button>
        <Button title='open the drawer right' onPress={this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer('drawerOpenRight'))}></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `drawerNavigator` can be `positioned` and Route named. `Position` can be set to **right** or **left**. Then open the `drawer` you want through the command.

**Example**

```js
let LeftSideMenuDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
...
    drawerOpenRoute: 'LeftSideMenu',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'LeftSideMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'LeftSideMenuToggle',
....
```

Usage

```js
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer('LeftSideMenu'));
```

Comment: Thanks, my friend I will try If it works I will let you know/